# A script to exclude specific vertices from Shapekeys?

Tags: rigging, shape-keys

I've created a bunch of Phonemes Shape Keys for my character. I unparented and re-parented the mesh to an armature. And this seems to have messed up the vertex assignments.

The phonemes are still okay-ish but I noticed that the there are unwanted vertices (around the eye) that are changing when turning up the shapekey value. Is there a way to "freeze" these vertices while activating my original phonemes shapekeys?

I'm so sorry I can't upload the file due to proprietary issues.

---

I reproduced the issue on the attached Suzanne head. The "Smile" shapekey involves vertices from the lips, and "wrong" vertices near the eyes. How can I keep the shapekey and yet exclude the eye vertices and make sure they don't interfere?

[image]

Comment: If you can not upload the file, I recommend create a simplified file to test with.

Comment: I did as suggested, thank you!

Comment: Hi, for future reference, you do not need to explain edits in the body of your question as it adds clutter. There is an edit history that handles that part for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer on BA! So all I need to do is to

- Select the Basis Shape Key, <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *edit mode*
- Select the vertices you want to keep unchanged,
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> *>Propagate to Shapes*.

And it will overwrite the vertices shapes in that particular area and thus will not change anymore. The downside is that it is going to apply it to all the shapes (my understanding) but that's ok for now.